# BlackBerry | event=recordError eventData="Could not start viewfinder for recording"

Tags: blackberry, java-me, video-capture

I'm using [a recording example from official BlackBerry site](https://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/documentation/working_with_video_1984791_11.html)

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import java.lang.*;
import javax.microedition.media.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.microedition.media.control.*;

//Create the application framework by extending the UiApplication class. 
//In main(), create an instance of the new class and invoke 
//enterEventDispatcher() to enable the app to receive events. 
//In the application constructor, invoke pushScreen() to display the custom 
//screen for the app. The VideoRecordingDemoScreen class represents 
//the custom screen.
public class VideoRecordingDemo extends UiApplication
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
       VideoRecordingDemo app = new VideoRecordingDemo();
       app.enterEventDispatcher();
  }

  public VideoRecordingDemo()
  {
       pushScreen(new VideoRecordingDemoScreen());
  }

//Create the framework for the custom screen by extending the MainScreen 
//class. Declare an instance of the VideoRecorderThread class.  
  private class VideoRecordingDemoScreen extends MainScreen  
  { 
      private VideoRecorderThread _recorderThread;

//In the VideoRecordingDemoScreen constructor, invoke setTitle() to specify the 
//title for the screen. Invoke addMenuItem() twice to add the menu items 
//that start and stop the recording.  
      public VideoRecordingDemoScreen()
      {
          setTitle("Video recording demo");

          addMenuItem(new StartRecording());
          addMenuItem(new StopRecording());
      }

//In the VideoRecordingDemoScreen class, define the menu items to start and stop 
//the recording. The menu items invoke the VideoRecorederThread.start() and 
//VideoRecorederThread.stop() methods.  
      private class StartRecording extends MenuItem 
      {
          public StartRecording() 
          {
              super("Start recording", 0, 100);
          }

          public void run() 
          {
              try 
              {
                  VideoRecorderThread newRecorderThread = new VideoRecorderThread();
                  newRecorderThread.start();
                  _recorderThread = newRecorderThread;
              }  
              catch (Exception e) 
              {
                  Dialog.alert(e.toString());
              }
          }
      }

      private class StopRecording extends MenuItem 
      {
          public StopRecording() 
          {
              super("Stop recording", 0, 100);
          }

          public void run() 
          {
              try 
              {
                  if (_recorderThread != null) 
                  { 
                      _recorderThread.stop();
                  }
              } 
              catch (Exception e) 
              {
                  Dialog.alert(e.toString());
              }
          }
      }

//In the VideoRecordingDemo screen class, define an inner class that extends 
//Thread and implements PlayerListener. In the class, create a variable of 
//type Player, and a variable of type RecordControl for recording media from 
//Player. You do not need to record video in a separate thread because 
//recording operations are threaded by design.
      private class VideoRecorderThread extends Thread implements 
            javax.microedition.media.PlayerListener
      {
          private Player _player;
          private RecordControl _recordControl;

          VideoRecorderThread()
          {
          }

//In the VideoRecorderThread class, implement run(). In run() create a try/catch 
//block and invoke Manager.createPlayer(String locator) to create a Player object 
//to capture video, using as a parameter a value that specifies the encoding 
//to use to record video.
          public void run() 
          {
              try 
              {
                  _player = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(
                              "capture://video?encoding=video/3gpp");
//Invoke Player.addPlayerListener(). Specify this as a parameter because 
//VideoRecorderThread implements PlayerListener.
                  _player.addPlayerListener(this);

//Invoke Player.realize() to initialize the VideoControl object.
                  _player.realize();

//Invoke Player.getControl("VideoControl") to retrieve the VideoControl object.  
                  VideoControl videoControl = 
                                   (VideoControl) _player.getControl("VideoControl");
                  _recordControl = (RecordControl) _player.getControl( "RecordControl" ); 

//Invoke VideoControl.initDisplayMode(int mode, Object arg). To initialize the mode 
//that a video field uses, pass an arg parameter to specify the UI primitive that 
//displays the video. Cast the returned object as a Field object. You can invoke 
//initDisplayMode() in different ways to return a Field (or an Item to display a 
//video on a Canvas class in a MIDlet).  
                  Field videoField = 
                      (Field) videoControl.initDisplayMode(VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE,
                      "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field");

                  try
                  {

//In a try/catch block, invoke VideoControl.setDisplaySize() to set the size of the 
//viewfinder to monitor your recording. In this example, the size is the full screen.
//Invoke add() to add the viewfinder to the screen.  
                      videoControl.setDisplaySize(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight() );
                  }
                  catch( MediaException me )
                  {
                      // setDisplaySize is not supported
                  }

                  add(videoField);

//Invoke RecordControl.setRecordLocation() to specify the location on the device 
//to save the video recording.  
                  _recordControl.setRecordLocation(
                       "file:///store/home/user/VideoRecordingTest.3gpp" );   

//Invoke RecordControl.startRecord() to start recording the video and start 
//playing the media from Player. Invoke Player.start() to start Player.  
                  _recordControl.startRecord(); 
                  _player.start();

              }
              catch( IOException e ) 
              {
                  Dialog.alert(e.toString());
              }
              catch( MediaException e ) 
              {
                  Dialog.alert(e.toString());
              }
          }

//In VideoRecorderThread, implement the Thread interface's stop method. Check that 
//Player is not null and invoke Player.close() to release the Player object's 
//resources. Then set the Player to null.  
          public void stop() 
          {
              if (_player != null) 
              {
                   _player.close();
                   _player = null;
              }

//Check that RecordControl is not null and invoke RecordControl.stopRecord() to 
//stop recording. In a try/catch block, invoke RecordControl.commit() to save 
//the recording to a specified file. Then set RecordControl to null.  
              if (_recordControl != null) 
              {
                  _recordControl.stopRecord();

                  try 
                  {
                      _recordControl.commit();
                  } 
                  catch (Exception e) 
                  {
                      Dialog.alert(e.toString());
                  }
                  _recordControl = null;
              } 
          }

//In VideoRecorderThread, implement the PlayerListener interface's 
//playerUpdate() method, which is invoked when the Player object generates an 
//event. In this example, information about the event is displayed.  
          public void playerUpdate(Player player, String event, Object eventData) 
          {
              Dialog.alert("Player " + player.hashCode() + " got event " + event + ": " 
                              + eventData);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

But I get error in PlayerListener with params:

```
event=recordError 
eventData="Could not start viewfinder for recording"
```

BlackBerry 9790 (OS 7.1)

Anybody faced with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap `_recordControl.startRecord()` and `_player.start()` statements helps me to solve this problem

Comment: Completely agree with you. Question has been updated.